# Centralized propagation of events at observer pattern

Tags: java, reflection, event-handling, polymorphism, observer-pattern

in a game we programmed in java, we quite often make use of observers. For the propagation of events we have loops like

```
for(Observer o : observers) {
   o.somethingHappened();
}
```

It works of course, but we have to write down this stupid loop for each and every event happening:

```
for(Observer o : observers) {
   o.somethingElseHappened();
}
```

Some time back I had the same thing in C++ and could make use of member function pointer and than write something like

```
dispatchEvent(&MyAbstractHandler::somethingHappened); //loop over observers for any "event" provided
```

..which seems as the best solution to me. But as Java isn't capable of this, I'm wondering what's the best solution.

You could use a Event-Object and pass it to a method handleEvent() that is overloaded for several Event-inheritants, so make use of polymorphism. But this gives you a ton of empty classes (and I'm generally critical about classes just for the sake of polymorphism). Also there is Reflection, but that doesn't seem like a typical use case and also there are performance issues.

So what are your thoughts on this? Am I missing a method?

Comment: Why not either use PropertyChangeSupport/PropertyChangeListener, or emulate what it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(speaking from an MMO developer's perspective)

I've found that, for scalability's sake, you may want to process event-handling in more than one thread; I've typically had a pattern like this:

```
 public class Event { EventType getType (); }
 // extend Event for special cases that require additional attributes…

 public class EventDispatcher {
       Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<Observer>> observers;
       void send (final Event e) {
            for (Observer o : observers.get(e.getClass())) {
                  o.receiveEvent (e);
            }
       }
  }
```

Or, you can use an `enum`:

```
  public enum EventType { … } ;
  …
  Map <EventType,List<Observer>> observers;
  …
       for (Observer o : observers.get(e.getEventType ()))  …
```

As you grow to handle more observers, you may need to partition the event handling and/or make it run in other threads. The `EventDispatcher.send(Event)` method gives you a single place to extend that, e.g. putting in spatial partitions (you can't detect this event, because you're too far away), or injecting Event objects into a queue for asynchronous processing on other thread(s), where the event-handler(s) won't affect the thread generating the event.

We originally began using this model for handling event propagation back to human players (so networking code was running synchronously on its own thread), but found that the queue system helped speed up AI and physics propagations as well.

The downside, perhaps, is that you then have to have a switch/case filter on your Observer class(es). That generally falls into a common base class, assuming that you have a reasonably small number of EventTypes to enumerate.

In earlier iterations of the Romance MMO core (and still supported in the 1.1 code base for backwards-compatibility), we used interfaces for receiving various events. (The base class hooks these into the general event receivers — which we call Actions to differentiate from UI Event handlers.)

```
 public interface EventFooHandler {
         public void handleEventFoo (int bar, int baz);
 };
 public class SomeObject implements EventFooHandler …
```

Perhaps these Interfaces were what you meant by “ton of empty classes?” This is generally the “colloquial Java right way to do it” for things that run in your own stack / thread; e.g. I believe Swing makes extensive use of “callback functions” this way, as do any number of other standard Java libraries.

Of course, if you don't want to simply implement the interfaces on each Observer, you can use anonymous classes…

```
    getEventDispatcher ().registerForEventFoo 
        ( new EventFooHandler {
               public void handleEventFoo (int bar, int baz) {
                      this.doGribble (bar + 2, baz);
             }});
```

If you're not biting the bullet and diving into Entity systems (I'm sure someone is bound to pop in and plug one, probably mentioning the joys of immutable state and 50% odds that they recommend switching to Erlang for your next project :-) ), I'd tend toward something similar to the former. The “uniform event” system allows the “plumbing” to be orthogonal, event→observer routing to be altered in a single place, and keeps from propagating miscellaneous methods on observers for every event type that you come up with as time goes by.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have event listeners which can trigger when they need to, for example I had a program which needed to update an Order view each time an order was modified. So I set up a PropertyChangeListener so that whenever certain properties were changed (i.e. the transactionsList) it would fire a method to update the JTable of the order.

You have to be careful when using those though, to avoid concurrency issues.

Here is some example code:

```
public Order makeNewOrder() {
    currentOrder = new Order();
    currentOrder.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            updateOrderTable();
        }
    });
    updateOrderTable();
    return currentOrder;
}
```

extracts from the Order class:

```
public class Order implements Serializable {
...
transient private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport
    = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
...
    public void addTL(...) {
    TransactionLine t = new TransactionLine(...);
    transactions.add(t);
    if (propertyChangeSupport != null)
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("transactions", false, true);
    }
//each instance should add this when created
public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}
```

This is the method which is called:

```
/** This method is fired on propertyChange */
public void updateOrderTable() {
    OrderTable ot = new OrderTable(currentOrder);
    currentOrderTable.setModel(ot.getTableModel());
    currentOrderTable.setColumnModel(ot.getColumnModel());
    savedOrdersSelector.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(getSavedOrders()));
    OrderSummary.setOrder(currentOrder);
}
```